# How do I print slurm variables to standard slurm output?

Tags: stdout, output, slurm

I want to print the following variables to the standard output file `slurm-XXXXX.out` produced by Slurm. Right now, I am generating a separate `.info` file for every job.

```
echo "SLURM Job ID        : ${SLURM_JOB_ID}" >> $SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR/$jobName.$JOBID.info
echo "SLURM Job name      : ${SLURM_JOB_NAME}" >> $SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR/$jobName.$JOBID.info
echo "SLURM Node list     : ${SLURM_JOB_NODELIST}" >> $SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR/$jobName.$JOBID.info
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just echoing these variables without the redirection to your info file will output to `.out` file, like

```
echo "SLURM Job ID        : ${SLURM_JOB_ID}"
```